# System event key codes not working on thunderbolt display

Tags: terminal, applescript, unix, thunderbolt-display

My AppleScript works when I am just using my MacBook Pro Retina, however if i have my Thunderbolt Display attached the script does not work.

Here is the script which works perfectly on just the laptop:

```
######## turn screen bright
repeat 25 times
    tell application "System Events"
        key code 113
    end tell
end repeat
```

Terminal will display this if i am running on the Thunderbolt Display:

`^[[28~^[[28~^{{` (repeats)

Does any one know the key code to adjust brightness on the Thunderbolt Display or where I may find it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of Mac OS X are you using? Are you using this with the MBP closed or open?

Comment: Im using 10.8.4 and i have the MBP open with it being its own display. the script does not effect either of the monitors when the display is plugged in. thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Did you try `key code 113 using control down`? Pressing the brightness keys while holding control normally changes the brightness of a Thunderbolt Display, but I don't know if it works with keys like F15.

You can also use [brightness.c](http://mattdanger.net/2008/12/adjust-mac-os-x-display-brightness-from-the-terminal/) to change the brightness of different displays:

```
do shell script "~/bin/brightness -d 1 0.0"
```

Comment: Using the brightness.c was something i have not thought of and probably makes more sense than a loop of system event key codes - thanks